# In Kotlin when using Kovenant Promise.of(value) sometimes I leak exceptions

Tags: kotlin, kovenant

Using Kovenant, I use `Promise.of(value)` function at times to create a synchronous result that I want to wrap as a promise.  But sometimes calls like:

```kotlin
Promise.of(callSomeCalculation())  <-- throws exception sometimes
  .then { ... }
  .then { ... }
  .fail { ex -> log.error(ex) }    <-- exception is not logged
```

This code loses exceptions that happen during the first promise.  Where did they go?  They are never logged.  And sometimes they just crash my app with unhandled exception.  Why isn't the promise catching them all?

**Note:** *this question is intentionally written and answered by the author ([Self-Answered Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)), so that solutions for interesting problems are shared in SO.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are leaking exceptions outside the chain of your promises.  Imagine this code:

```
fun makeMyPromise(): Promise<Int, Exception> {
    val result: Int = callSomeCalculation()  // <--- exception occurs here
    val deferred = deferred<Int, Exception>()
    deferred.resolve(result)
    return deferred.promise
}
```

This is basically what  your code is doing in the first line.  And if an exception is thrown the method will exit with the exception and `deferred.reject` is never called.  Changing the code to this:

```
fun makeMyPromise(): Promise<Int, Exception> {
    val deferred = deferred<Int, Exception>()
    try {
        val result: Int = callSomeCalculation()  // <--- exception occurs here
        deferred.resolve(result)
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        deferred.reject(ex)
    }
    return deferred.promise
}
```

Would be more correct and catch your exception.  And it ensures nothing could leak from the promise chain.

So going back to your original code, your `callSomeCalculation()` is happening before the `Promise.of()` method is called and there is no way it can provide this sort of protection.  It happens before Kovenant has an idea you are even creating a promise.  So you need a new `Promise.of(lambda)` method that accepts a code block that can be completely protected against such leaks.

Here is a new `Promise.of(lambda)` extension function:

```
fun <V> Promise.Companion.of(codeBlock: () -> V): Promise<V, Exception> {
    val deferred = deferred<V, Exception>()
    try {
        deferred.resolve(codeBlock())
    }
    catch (ex: Exception) {
        deferred.reject(ex)
    }
    return deferred.promise
}
```

Which would be used as:

```
Promise.of { callSomeCalculation() }   <-- sometimes throws exception
  .then { ... }
  .then { ... }
  .fail { ex -> log.error(ex) }        <-- exception ALWAYS logged!
```

Notice the parenthesis `()` changed to `{}` brackets because now the code block is being passed into the `Promise.of` method and wrapped with exception handling, preventing any leaks.  You will now see your exception logged in the later `fail { .. }` block.

Comment: This seems to be an alternative to using `task` method: http://kovenant.komponents.nl/api/core_usage/#task. Could you explain in answer when it should be used instead of `task`?

Comment: synchronous (Promise.of vs. async (task) dispatching of the code, but making sure the calculated value doesn't leak the exception.

Comment: Another thing that concerns me with the proposed `Promise.of` overload is that now its behavior is unexpected when one wants to have a promise of functional type `Promise<() -> V>`, but gets `Promise<V>` instead.

Comment: It could have a different name if that was your concern.  I'm not trying to add to the Kovenant library, where he would need to consider those options.  I'm suggesting a model for not leaking exceptions where I've seen developers leak them too many times.  And an example of that includes making it re-usable, and someone will have to pick the best name for that.  As a private helper class you can consider your world in which you need to name things and what functionality you might have, if this is for Kovenant as a feature suggestion he'll have to consider the WHOLE world.